# Exception in thread "main" java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Tags: java, http

I don't know what is happening. Code is executing for 8-16 hours and then stops the execution of the program. Why? Can any one help on this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)     
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:133)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    at example.producer.Spout6.main(Spout6.java:79)
```

Comment: What about the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221290/noroutetohostexception-in-client

Comment: Consider possibility that "no route to host" actually mean "no route to host" - currently post has no indication that it is not the case (nor any research to prove/disprove that)

Comment: the issue was solved but now im getting the exception like java.net.UnknownHostException: api.twitter.com
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
code works for 18 to 20 hours and then throws the Exception. can you help me on how to reslove it -Alexei Levenkov

Answer (score 7):

The exception typically indicates a network routing problem of some kind.  This may be the result of a problem with the network configuration in you LAN or WAN, or it may be a result of a network link or switch outage.  It can even be cause by failure of the host that you are trying to talk to.

IMO, it is unlikely to be a network firewall issue, though that is also possible.  (Normally a firewall will simply discard packets to block traffic, and that is most likely to result in connection timeouts.  However, a firewall *could* respond with an Destination Unreachable packet that would result in this exception.)

Answer (score 3):

Could be a firewall... Or something like internet...Or too many ports...Here are the details:

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to
>   a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be
>   reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate
>   router is down.

Java docs

Also, you may be running out of available ports:

> Another important ramification of the ephemeral port range is that it
>   limits the maximum number of connections from one machine to a
>   specific service on a remote machine! The TCP/IP protocol uses the
>   connection's 4-tuple to distinguish between connections, so if the
>   ephemeral port range is only 4000 ports wide, that means that there
>   can only be 4000 unique connections from a client machine to a remote
>   service at one time.
>   (http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html)

Do this to get available ports to check:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range 
32768   61000
```

**Note:**

**It's certainly not a problem with the code**, instead, try to **keep** a good connection by changing firewall settings, or getting stronger connection. Also, check the available ports by doing what I told you above.

Answer (score 3):

It could be the issue with firewall

If you are using Linux then follow steps:

Stop the firewall: > service iptables stop

allow the port you want to connect on the host: > ufw allow [port_number]